# AutoIT - Save to Notepad instead of MsgBox

Tags: autoit

I'm new to coding, I've been trying various code segments that I have found online however cannot get the below code to save the array to a notepad instead of in a MsgBOX.

If someone could please give me the answer and adjust the code so that it saves to a notepad instead of displaying in a msgbox, I learn alot better from taking apart working code as apose to trying to adapt/fix broken/wrong code.

I would appreciate it very much!.

Thanks
Copper

```
Global $Array = _WinGetCtrlInfo(WinGetTitle(''))
Global $sOne = '[0][0] = ' & $Array[0][0] & @CR, $sTwo
For $iCC = 1 To $Array[0][0]
    $sOne &= '[' & $iCC & '][0] = ' & $Array[$iCC][0] & @CR
    $sTwo &= '[' & $iCC & '][1] = ' & $Array[$iCC][1] & @CR
Next
MsgBox(64, 'WinInfo', StringTrimRight($sOne, 1) & @CR & StringTrimRight($sTwo, 1))

Func _WinGetCtrlInfo($hWin)
    If IsString($hWin) Then $hWin = WinGetHandle($hWin)
    Local $sClassList = WinGetClassList($hWin), $iAdd, $aDLL, $sHold
    Local $sSplitClass = StringSplit(StringTrimRight($sClassList, 1), @LF), $aReturn[1][2]
    For $iCount = UBound($sSplitClass) - 1 To 1 Step - 1
        Local $nCount = 0
        While 1
            $nCount += 1
            If ControlGetHandle($hWin, '', $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount) = '' Then ExitLoop
            If Not StringInStr(Chr(1) & $sHold, Chr(1) & $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount & Chr(1)) Then
                $sHold &= $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount & Chr(1)
                $iAdd += 1
                ReDim $aReturn[$iAdd][2]
                $aReturn[$iAdd - 1][0] = $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount
                $aDLL = DllCall('User32.dll', 'int', 'GetDlgCtrlID', 'hwnd', _
                    ControlGetHandle($hWin, '', $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount))
                If @error = 0 Then
                    $aReturn[$iAdd - 1][1] = $aDLL[0]
                Else
                    $aReturn[$iAdd - 1][1] = ''
                EndIf
            EndIf
        WEnd
    Next
    $aReturn[0][0] = $iAdd - 1
    Return $aReturn
EndFunc
```

The current code above works fine and will compile a list of controlNN however the software I'm using it with has hundreds of different controlNN and so it won't fit into a message-box, I've searched online and tried to adjust it to save in a notepad but keep having issues.

Thanks again
Copper

Comment: You should really try to do the tutorials from the [AutoIt help](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/) first... Theres an example of how to automate [Notepad](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/notepad/notepad.htm). You should try `ClipPut(StringTrimRight($sOne, 1) & @CR & StringTrimRight($sTwo, 1))` instead of using the MsgBox and then use `Send("^c")` on Notepad.

Comment: If you already have your array and you want to save it why not using _FileWriteFromArray ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoit inbuilt function 'FileWrite' here in place of MsgBox.

```
Global $Array = _WinGetCtrlInfo(WinGetTitle(''))
Global $sOne = '[0][0] = ' & $Array[0][0] & @CR, $sTwo
For $iCC = 1 To $Array[0][0]
    $sOne &= '[' & $iCC & '][0] = ' & $Array[$iCC][0] & @CR
    $sTwo &= '[' & $iCC & '][1] = ' & $Array[$iCC][1] & @CR
Next

;MsgBox(64, 'WinInfo', StringTrimRight($sOne, 1) & @CR & StringTrimRight($sTwo, 1))

FileWrite("D:/notepad.txt",StringTrimRight($sOne, 1) & @CR & StringTrimRight($sTwo, 1))

Func _WinGetCtrlInfo($hWin)
    If IsString($hWin) Then $hWin = WinGetHandle($hWi   n)
    Local $sClassList = WinGetClassList($hWin), $iAdd, $aDLL, $sHold
    Local $sSplitClass = StringSplit(StringTrimRight($sClassList, 1), @LF), $aReturn[1][2]
    For $iCount = UBound($sSplitClass) - 1 To 1 Step - 1
        Local $nCount = 0
        While 1
            $nCount += 1
            If ControlGetHandle($hWin, '', $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount) = '' Then ExitLoop
            If Not StringInStr(Chr(1) & $sHold, Chr(1) & $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount & Chr(1)) Then
                $sHold &= $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount & Chr(1)
                $iAdd += 1
                ReDim $aReturn[$iAdd][2]
                $aReturn[$iAdd - 1][0] = $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount
                $aDLL = DllCall('User32.dll', 'int', 'GetDlgCtrlID', 'hwnd', _
                    ControlGetHandle($hWin, '', $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount))
                If @error = 0 Then
                    $aReturn[$iAdd - 1][1] = $aDLL[0]
                Else
                    $aReturn[$iAdd - 1][1] = ''
                EndIf
            EndIf
        WEnd
    Next
    $aReturn[0][0] = $iAdd - 1
    Return $aReturn
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `MsgBox` you could run Notepad and use [`Send()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) to type the text into Notepad.

```
Global $Array = _WinGetCtrlInfo(WinGetTitle(''))
Global $sOne = '[0][0] = ' & $Array[0][0] & @CR, $sTwo
For $iCC = 1 To $Array[0][0]
    $sOne &= '[' & $iCC & '][0] = ' & $Array[$iCC][0] & @CR
    $sTwo &= '[' & $iCC & '][1] = ' & $Array[$iCC][1] & @CR
Next
Run("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Unbenannt - Editor")
Send($sOne)
Send($sTwo)
```

Note that you have to modify the title of the empty Notepad window to match with your localisation.

Here's an interesting tutorial about this topic:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/notepad/notepad.htm

As an alternative you could follow Xenobiologist's suggestion and use [`_FileWriteFromArray`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileWriteFromArray.htm) to directly write to a file and then open this file in Notepad, which is a lot faster:

```
#include <File.au3>
Global $Array = _WinGetCtrlInfo(WinGetTitle(''))
_FileWriteFromArray(@DesktopDir & "\output.txt", $Array)
Run("notepad.exe " & @DesktopDir & "\output.txt", @WindowsDir, @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```